# Blue Devil effect on water pumps

Tags: ford, cooling-system, leak, water-pump, explorer

I used Blue Devil Head Gasket Sealer on my 2006 Ford Explorer about 6 months ago, and it's worked. However, I am now noticing some antifreeze dripping on my garage floor, which seems to be coming from my 7 month old water pump.

Does Blue Devil have any adverse effect on water pumps ??

Comment: That is hard to say. There are mixed reviews on the web about Blue Devil effects on the cooling system. IMO, before blaming anything or anyone, you need to find out where the leak is actually coming from. It could be a bad gasket or the pump may have gone bad (it can happen).

Comment: Thanks CharlieRB. Makes sense. The small leaking is coming from the port hole on the water pump.  The coolant leaking is thicker of course, and before I replaced water pump I thought I should get some feedback. Thanks for your time and thoughts.

Comment: If it is coming out of the weep hole you describe, it means that it is leaking past the seal around the shaft which connects the pulley (on the outside) to the blades (on the inside). The seal is there to keep the coolant away from the shaft's ball-bearings. I (personally) don't think that the Blue Devil stuff would destroy the seal; otherwise it would cause problems in all cars. Your new water pump might have a defective seal.

Answer (score 2):

Blue devil is great but not for water pumps.I have used it many times to repair head gaskets,hell even in rotary motors.But it does destroy water pumps. 2 brand new weiand small block chevy water pumps and also 2 other water pumps after it was installed.It always made them weap shortly after using the product.

Comment: @Carguy I agree with you completely, but it is best to mindful that actual users sometimes have very different experiences.  That said, when someone says that a product has destroyed their water pumps, that's enough for me to want to avoid it for that application!

Answer (score -1):

I used blue devil on a 2014 Ford Fusion eco boost 1.5l engine just 3 months after replacing the coolant pump. Now it leaks a gallon of coolant every mile.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/66346)